# Pushwoosh - Send single notification to multiple applications

Tags: android, ios, iphone, push-notification, pushwoosh

This is more of a configuration based question. I am trying to send a single push notification to multiple application using [**Pushwoosh Application Group**](http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/application-groups). Just for testing I tried to send a test push notification from **Pushwoosh**. I have two applications under this group which are installed on my device. But I am getting two different notifications. I have set different app codes for two apps which I got from **Pushwoosh**.

Comment: Could you please contact Pushwoosh support? I think that would be a better place to find the answer rather than here.

Comment: Can you show the logs from the both of apps? especially registerDevice request?